# Is it possible to associate a user-defined-type (UDT) with a XML schema on SQL?

Tags: sql, xml

Is it possible to associate a user-defined-type (UDT) with a XML schema on SQL?

I want to create a UDT that has a XML type attribute and force the user to use a specific XML schema when using the referred UDT.

I know that it is possible to associate a XML schema with a XML type attribute that is in a table (example bellow) but I did not find anything about it concerning UDTs.

```
CREATE TABLE xwarehouses OF XMLTYPE
   XMLSCHEMA "http://www.oracle.com/xwarehouses.xsd"
   ELEMENT "Warehouse";
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DBMS are you really using? Don't just add a bunch of DBMS tags to attract more people.

Comment: I want a generic solution to be used withing any DBMS. That is the way I used many DBMS tags.

Comment: You will never get a generic solution (for one, because `create table ... of type` is non-standard to begin with). SQL Server doesn't even support UDT that way. If at all you might find a way to associate a schema with a XML _column_

Comment: It is probably true, but I want to be sure about it.

Comment: Pehaps someone knows a good solution. 
Lets see...

Comment: When you want a generic solution, instead of tagging multiple DBMS tags, don't tag any instead.

Comment: There is no "generic" solution.  Really.

Comment: Please click @a_horse_with_no_name's profile. I think he knows what he is talking about. XML support varies considerably across RDBMS's and some like MySQL/SQLite do not have any at all.